# why do configs retrieved by eglGetConfigs give me EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID of zero

Tags: configuration, opengl-es, framebuffer

I call eglGetConfigAttrib with EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID and it lists 0 for each one.
Configs retrieved with specific  attrbitue lists and eglChooseConfig seem to work correctly.
As does retriving other attributtes with eglGetConfigAttrib.

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to me like a problem I encountered with the NVIDIA Tegra 2 drivers for my Trim-Slice. In my case it turned out to be a driver-bug, which has since been fixed. If you're using NVIDIA as well, perhaps upgrading the driver will help?